# Why is MaxPower for internal root hubs 0mA?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, power-management

Out of pure curiosity, I'm trying to figure out how USB power delivery is handled in Linux. What I'm seeing is that MaxPower for external devices is set to reasonable numbers depending on the device; however, the internal root hub has `MaxPower` set to `0mA`. Is this a special case for the root hub? Does the kernel ignore internal hubs when determining the maximum power available at each hop along the path to a leaf device?

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    MaxPower                0mA
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b6d9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
    MaxPower              500mA
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 18d1:4ee1 Google Inc. Nexus/Pixel Device (MTP)
    MaxPower              500mA
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
    MaxPower              100mA
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
    MaxPower               50mA
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    MaxPower                0mA
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to define a maximum current draw for a root hub. From which bus is it supposed to be drawing that current? It's the source of all buses.

Comment: As in - MaxPower is the maximum amount a device can *demand*, not the maximum amount it can *supply*?

Comment: Exactly, that's the thing!